# Why store isn't just an immutable data type without logic in flux/redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

From redux doc ([http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html][1]):

> A store is not a class. It's just an object with a few methods on it.

and the methods are:

> - getState()
> - dispatch(action)
> - subscribe(listener)
> - replaceReducer(nextReducer)

(In flux it is is similar, with a difference that there is also an ActionDispatcher (and possibly an EventEmitter), but Store(s) are registered to the ActionDispatcher, so they are coupled.)

The question is why? Why store is not just a decoupled data type without logic, preferably an immutable one.

The following pseudo code is an example to show what I am trying to say. I used "appState" word instead of "store", as it is more natural to me:

```
const initialAppState = require("./initial-app-state.json");

function main() {
  var actionDispatcher = new ActionDispatcher();
  var appState;
  actionDispatcher.register(function onAction(action) {
     var newAppState = appState = reducers_combined(appState: ?AppState, action); //apply the action to appState, and create a new app state; as state is immutable
     var newAppProps = createAppProps(newAppState); //we can write the createAppProps function, which takes an app state and create all the props to be passed down to the root component
     ReactDom.render(React.createElement(App, newAppProps), document.getElementById("root"));
  });
  actionDispatcher.dispatch({
     type: "LOAD_APP_REQUESTED",
     appState: recordify(initialAppState); //we can write the recordify function that turns initialAppState JSONValue to an Immutable Record
  })
}
```

As above we can create our ActionDispatcher single instance in our main function, and register an onAction callback to it, which has access to the current app state via closure, and will in turn create the new app state, update the current app state reference to the newly created one, create new app props with respect to the new app state and render it. The views will dispatch actions to the actionDispatcher directly (the actionDispatcher instance can be passed down the component tree via context) or indirectly.

What is the rationale making the Store work, instead of just hold? Are there any advantages?

Comment: you could have your state tree as a separate object than the store but you will still need to keep the reference in the store to pass it along to build the reducer and middleware chains.The gain of separating them does not justify the complexity in implementation in my opinion.

Comment: I do not "need to" keep the refence of state  in store. As I say we do not need store, just a state tree without logic. I am questioning why the api is designed that way before following it through,, so the complexity of following it through does not make any sense. Then we should not follow it through, right?

Comment: the store needs to be aware of the state in order to pass it around to reducers and whoever needs to get a hold of he state. if you don't want to keep the reference of the plain state in the store where would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik because in redux when creating a store a reducer is required.

The store is usually created with `createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])`.

The functions mentioned in your question are utility function useful when working with the store.